# How can scanf work before its previous line?

Tags: c

In the following code, when I enter anything in [a-z] followed by \n for `c`, it accepts and prints 'enter d'. But when I give any numbers for `c`, that value is scanned for variable `d` and then then only 'enter d' displayed. How does this happen?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char c[10],d[10];
    int i,j;

    printf("enter c:");
    i=scanf("%[a-z]%1[\n]",c);

    printf("\nenter d:");
    j=scanf("%[ 0-9]%1[\n]",d);

    printf("\nc : %s-%d\n",c,i);
    printf("\nd : %s-%d\n",d,j);
 }
```

My output is:

```
enter c:12

enter d:c:�-0

d:12-2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to skip over whitespace, like the ending newline, then add a leading space before the format code:

```
printf("enter c: ");
i = scanf(" %s", c);

printf("enter c: ");
j = scanf(" %s", d);
```

This will make `scanf` skip all whitespace.

Also, if you want to read a number, why not read it as a number using e.g. the `"%d"` format code? If you want it as a string, then use e.g. `snprintf` to convert it after scanning.

Comment: but how can second scanf happen before second printf?

Comment: @Karthik If you check the output, it says the result from the first `scanf` (i.e. `i`) is `0` meaning nothing was scanned.

Comment: absolutely.but how did second scanf worked before prompting 'enter d' ? actually ,i gave nothing after entering 12 and \n.

Comment: @Karthik The stdout stream is buffered, so will only display what's in the buffer after it reaches a newline.

Comment: @Karthik Like Dayal rai says. Because the first input is not scanned, it's still in the input buffer. So when the second scan is made it reads that instead of new input.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But now I tried fflush(stdin) after scanning 'c'. but same result still ..?

Comment: @Karthik Don't call `fflush` on `stdin`, it's use is unspecified in the C standard, and only some platforms support it.

Comment: @Karthik Also, see [here](http://ideone.com/XkvmCW) for a working version. I also suggest you look into using `fgets` to get the line, and then use e.g. `sscanf` to extract the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *c = malloc(10);
    char *d = malloc(10);

    int i = 0;

    printf("enter c:");
    int x = EOF;
    while (( x = getchar()) != '\n' && x != EOF) {
        if (i >= 10) {
            break;
        }
        if (x >= 97 && x <= 122) {
            c[i++]=(char)x;
        }
    }
    printf("\nenter d:");
    x = EOF;
    i = 0;
    while (( x = getchar()) != '\n' && x != EOF) {
        if (i >= 10) {
            break;
        }
        if (x >= 48 && x <= 57) {
            d[i++]=(char)x;
        }
    }
    printf("\nc : %s\n",c);
    printf("\nd : %s\n",d);
    return 1;
 }
```